# Delete a row from a gridview outside the deleterow method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to delete a row outside the RowDeleting Method.
I'm trying to do that this way, but it asks for the sender and the row to delete, but I get a conversion error.

Can't convert type gridview row to gridview delete event args

here's my code, do you notice anything wrong?

```
grdContact_RowDeleting((object)grdContact, (GridViewDeleteEventArgs)grdContact.Rows[0]);





protected void grdContact_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{            
    List<DettagliFattura> app = (List<DettagliFattura>)Session["lst_dettagli"];
    app.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);

    Session["lst_dettagli"] = app;
    FillGrid();
    CalcolaTotale();
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you doing this? `app.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);` in `RowDeleting` event may not work as expected if you have paging for `GridView`.

Comment: Well, I want a gridview to be shown on my pageload, but at first it is empty. I want it to be shown, so I've added a blank row. Then I want to delete it

Comment: I am not getting, what you commented and your code don't relate. Why are you trying to delete if you don't want to show on page load?

Comment: yes i got it you want to show a empty grid with add new button so you can use empty template in grid view and append the html of the grid view

Comment: My gridview was empty at first. This means that it won't be shown. So I've added a new "fake" empty row. Now I want to delete it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: to what extent do you need it "shown".  Doing something like this: **`GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No Data"`**  will show the table without the need to add fake rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a empty template as show below by using tr and td

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="coursetxt"></asp:TextBox>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lbladd3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Universitytxt"></asp:TextBox>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="sdatetxt"></asp:TextBox>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="endtxt"></asp:TextBox>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnInsertRecordedu" runat="server" CssClass="buttonpop" Text="Add" ValidationGroup="edu" CommandName="Insert_emptydatatemplate" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
```